# Android: Display image over an Image in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I'm using `LinearLayout` to place two `ImageView` horizontally. I have image placed on `ImageView`. Now I need to add an small image over the image on `ImageView`. I have seen a lot of post but all of them deals with `Relativelayout` or `Framelayout`. Here is the XML code segment that I have used.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgmode31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="180dp"
        android:maxWidth="140dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/i5" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgmode32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:maxHeight="180dp"
        android:maxWidth="280dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/i1" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what a linear layout is supposed to prevent.  You may however be able to override the positioning of the next element using negative padding.  The problem with that is what happens on different screen densities.

I think this is what a surface view is meant for.  It provides a transparent drawing surface over the entire screen allowing you to draw in top of other views.

One last idea would be to place your first image in a frame layout inside your linear layout.  Then you could add your superimposed image to the frame layout using padding to position it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it easily with relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView     
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
     android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/i5"
     android:id="@+id/imgmode31" 
     android:maxHeight="180dp" 
     android:maxWidth="140dp">
   </ImageView>
   <ImageView     
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
     android:scaleType="fitXY" 
     android:longClickable="false"  
     android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
     android:src="@drawable/i1" 
     android:id="@+id/imgmode32" 
     android:maxHeight="180dp" 
     android:maxWidth="280dp">
   </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

if you want `ImagView` to overlap each other then make their `Height` and `Width` same and you can also bring any of the `ImageView` at front in runtime

Comment: -1 for ugly formatting, but +1 for having the correct answer. I will leave you at 0!

Comment: @Justin thanks for pointing out my formating as even i was not knowing that i have pasted such bad formated code. may be i did it from my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

A `LinearLayout` places elements linearly, one next to the other. If you want to place an element on top of another, then you need to resort to a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

If you change your `LinearLayout` to a `FrameLayout` you should see the two `ImageView`s overlapping.